# How to sum alias fields with date range

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I need to show SUM value of alias table that has value of the result from multiplying 2 fields.

Here is **asset** table:

```
+----------+-----+------------+
|  price   | qty |  tanggal   |
+----------+-----+------------+
|  6775000 |   1 | 2019-03-30 |
|  4760000 |   2 | 2019-03-25 |
|  7800000 |   2 | 2019-04-01 |
| 13599000 |   1 | 2019-03-30 |
+----------+-----+------------+
```

I've already tried:

```
SELECT 
SUM((price*qty)) 
AS worth 
FROM asset 
WHERE DATE(tanggal) >= 2019-03-25 AND DATE(tanggal) <= 2019-03-30
```

Also using BETWEEN clause like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM((price*qty)) 
AS worth 
FROM asset 
WHERE DATE(tanggal) BETWEEN 2019-03-25 AND 2019-03-30
```

> It keeps giving me *NULL* value, but if I remove the `WHERE` clause it
>   works fine and give me value of **45494000**. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you declared tanggal as DATE datatype?

Comment: Yes, I did sir.

Comment: 2019-03-30 is evaluated as 2019 minus 3 minus 30...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding single quotes, right know you are only doing a subtraction

```
SELECT SUM((price*qty)) AS worth 
FROM asset 
WHERE tanggal >= '2019-03-25' AND tanggal <= '2019-03-30'
```